# Vector of objects as a static class member

Tags: c++, oop

I have a following snippet of code:

```
class Person {
        std::string name_;
        std::string surname_;
        //static vector<???> tracer_;
    public:
        Person(std:: string name, std::string surname)
            : name_(name)
            , surname_(surname) {
                //something with tracer_
        }
        ~Person() {
            //something with tracer_
        }
        static void OutputPersons(std::ostream& out) {
            //print every element in tracer_
        }
};

class Worker {
        Person person_;
        std::string position_;
    public:
        Worker(const Person& person, std::string position)
            : person_(person)
            , position_(position) {
        }
};
```

What I want to achieve, is to print all instances of objects of class Person (name and surname, without position from class Worker) which exists at particular moment, so in example

```
Person s("aaa", "bbb");
Person t("ccc", "ddd");
{
    Person u("eee", "fff");
}
Worker w(Person("ggg","hhh"),"guard");
Person::OutputPersons(std::cout);
```

should print only

```
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
ggg hhh
```

as only these objects exists at the moment of calling Person::OutputPersons.

What I don't know is how to project class Person fields. As you see, I have been trying to make a static vector which should "trace" all objects of Person - with adding an element in constructor and removing in destructor. I only have a problem with type of elements in this vector, as I cannot put there any kind of pointer to class Person object.

EDIT:

As I get known it's legitimate to have a vector of Person*, I modified my code

```
class Person {
        std::string name_;
        std::string surname_;
        static std::vector<Person *> tracer_;
    public:
        Person(std:: string name, std::string surname)
            : name_(name)
            , surname_(surname) {
            tracer_.push_back(this);
        }
```

but I'm getting error "undefined reference to 'Person::tracer_'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not?   std::vector<Person *> is a perfectly legitimate type.

Comment: Or `std::vector<Person const*>`. The pointer you need is `this`.

Comment: Is it fully correct to use pointer to class A as a class A member? I haven't known this, but if it's true my problem is solved.

Comment: @MateuszKowalski Yes, that is perfectly acceptable and exactly how you should solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your comment, yes, it is perfectly valid to have pointers to a class a data members in your class.

However, there are a few modifications that you need to make to your code. For instance, in your setup the "ggg hhh" Person is not displayed because it is a temporary object whose destructor is called immediately after it is passed to the function. In order to catch this object, you have to add a user-defined copy-constructor to catch the object created in the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Person 
{

private:

    std::string name_;
    std::string surname_;

    static std::vector<Person*> tracer_;

public:

    Person(std:: string name, std::string surname)
        : name_(name), 
          surname_(surname) 
    {
        tracer_.push_back(this);     //add the person
    }

    //copy constructor
    Person(const Person& p) : name_(p.name_), surname_(p.surname_)
    {
          tracer_.push_back(this);                  //add the person
    }

    ~Person() 
    {
       tracer_.erase(std::remove(tracer_.begin(), tracer_.end(), this), tracer_.end());                               //remove the person, little messy
    }

    static void OutputPersons(std::ostream& out) 
    {
        for (std::vector<Person*>::iterator it = tracer_.begin(); it != tracer_.end(); it++)              //iterate through vector and print all members
        {
            out << (*it)->name_ << ' ' << (*it)-> surname_ << '\n';
        }
    }
};

class Worker 
{
private:

    Person person_;
    std::string position_;

public:

    Worker(const Person& person, std::string position)
        : person_(person),
          position_(position) 
    {

    }
};
```

To answer your new question, you must define tracer_outside of your class like this:

```
std::vector<Person*> Person::tracer_;
```

That's just how static class variables work in C++.

With these modifications, the output is:

```
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
ggg hhh
```

Note: it would probably be a better design for `Worker` to inherit from `Person` rather than maintain a `Person` field.